# "future I" vs. "future me"

Tags: word-usage

Consider the following conversation

> A: How do you relieve your stress and anxiety?
>
> B: I would imagine there are two of me, one is at the moment, the other comes from 10 years later. The **future I** talks to **current me**, "I know you are facing those problems ..., because I've been through all of them. Let me tell you, none of them is a big deal, you just need some rest. Call Tom and Bob, hang out with them, have a drink. Tomorrow you'll find everything is better."

I [googled it](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=nd3dXq26OuqSr7wP59i3eA&q=%22future%20I%22%20vs.%20%22future%20me%22&oq=%22future%20I%22%20vs.%20%22future%20me%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIICCEQFhAdEB4yCAghEBYQHRAeMggIIRAWEB0QHjIICCEQFhAdEB4yCAghEBYQHRAeUMcqWMcqYJEwaAFwAHgAgAHfAYgB3wGSAQMyLTGYAQCgAQKgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6sAEA&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjt_O22zvHpAhVqyYsBHWfsDQ8Q4dUDCAc&uact=5&safe=images) but the results include all kinds of version and I can't tell which one is correct.

Should I use "future me", "future I" or "future self" there?

Should I use "current me", "current I" or "current self" there?

Comment: I would suggest never mixing the two. For instance, don't say *the future **I** talks to the current **me**.* If you mix them, it looks bizarre. Whichever you use after *future* also use after *current*. Personally, I would also never use *I*. You are objectifying yourself, so you shouldn't be using the subjective pronoun. I would say *the future me talks to the current me* or *my future self talks to my current self*. But either of those would be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this concept is a *fantasy* scenario, there isn't really any precedent for how one should say this outside of creative works of fiction. Creative writing adheres to the rules of grammar but often plays with them for effect, so some may answer differently but that would be opinion-based.

As "I" is a pronoun, and "me" an object, you wouldn't say "I" about anybody else, even though in this fantasy scenario the other person is you from the future. You can't point at somebody else and use the pronoun "I", so "Future I" is just wrong.

"Future *me*" *is* used - there is even a website "futureme.org" where you can write a letter to yourself in the future. In fantasy where a person meets themself they often start referring to themselves as an object to explain the identity crisis, eg "*I am me!*".

However, the most grammatically pleasing way to refer to yourself from the future would be "*my future self*". [This ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=future%20me%2Cmy%20future%20self&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfuture%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmy%20future%20self%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cfuture%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmy%20future%20self%3B%2Cc0) compares usage of the two (note that a search  of "future I" turns up results due to sentences like "in the future I will...", so this is not reliable)

As to the issue of how you refer to your *present* self - before you get to your problematic sentence, you already set the scene by saying that there are two people - you, and your future self. So, if you correctly identify your future self there is really no need to say anything special to identify the only other person in the conversation, so all you need to say is:

> I talk to my future self.

or

> My future self talks to me.